# How to get onEdit Trigger torun specifically on sheet and not whole spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i was wondering if anyone could help me with getting this script to only trigger when edits are made on "Mirror" and not other sheets on the spreadsheet. the rest of the script runs perfectly but just triggers way to much.

```
function buildReport() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = ss.getSheetByName('Mirror').getRange("A1:B13").getValues();
  let payload = buildAlert(data);
  sendAlert(payload);
}
//rest of code after
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Again, i just need to have the script fire only when edits are made to the "Mirror" sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function buildReport(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Mirror") {
    let data = sh.getRange("A1:B13").getValues();
    let payload = buildAlert(data);
    sendAlert(payload);
  }
}
```

More than one sheet:

```
function buildReport(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet1','Sheet2',...];
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())) {
    let data = sh.getRange("A1:B13").getValues();
    let payload = buildAlert(data);
    sendAlert(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: i cant get it to produce any alerts.  i just get the "Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
buildReport" and nothing when make edits. do i need to set up a trigger?

Comment: Your question on involved getting it to run on only one sheet.   I don't have any knowledge about anything else.  If wish to know more then please provide a [mcve] that produces the problem along with a definition of buildAlert() and sendAlert();

Answer (score 2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (name != 'Mirror') return;

  // your code

}
```